# Is it possible to POST to an action if the system is offline?

Tags: plugin-development, form

There are easier ways to do this for sure, but...

I have the [Mailchimp Subscribe](https://github.com/aelvan/mailchimp-subscribe-craft) plugin installed to build our email list etc... and it works perfectly!

However, we are now building a "Coming Soon" page with the site turned off to the public while we build out the site.

Is it possible to accept a certain action while the system is offline so that the POST request is accepted and doesnt return a 503 error?

Again, this is possible through using just a Mailchimp form itself but I'm interested to see if this sort of thing is possible if I ever needed this sort of control in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completely untested, but something like this in your `craft/config/general.php` file should work:

```
return array(
   'isSystemOn' => (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && !$_REQUEST['action'] != 'mailchimpSubscribe/list/Subscribe'),
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work with the following. `'isSystemOn' => (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && !$_REQUEST['action'] != 'mailchimpSubscribe/list/Subscribe'),`